# IntelliJ doesn't start browser when spring context loaded

Tags: spring-mvc, intellij-idea

How can I do to start the browser when spring is loaded in IntelliJ ?

Here my tomcat config : 
http://imageshack.com/i/p5fFKGEfp

I've defined to launch the browser, but nothing appends..

Here the end of my logs :

```
18:21:25.192 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher' processing GET request for [/]
18:21:25.193 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /
18:21:25.193 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Returning handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.excilys.formation.controller.impl.ThumbnailControllerImpl.doGet()]
18:21:25.193 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'thumbnailControllerImpl'
18:21:25.194 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/] is: -1
18:21:25.195 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'welcome'; URL [/WEB-INF/pages/welcome.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
18:21:25.195 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView - Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/pages/welcome.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'welcome'
18:21:25.197 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
18:21:27.413 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher' processing GET request for [/]
18:21:27.413 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /
18:21:27.414 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Returning handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.excilys.formation.controller.impl.ThumbnailControllerImpl.doGet()]
18:21:27.414 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'thumbnailControllerImpl'
18:21:27.414 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/] is: -1
18:21:27.415 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'welcome'; URL [/WEB-INF/pages/welcome.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
18:21:27.415 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView - Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/pages/welcome.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'welcome'
18:21:27.415 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

The context is loaded without error isn't it ? What's wrong ?

Comment: "The context is loaded without error isn't it ?"  Dunno.  The logs here are too brief to say for sure.  Have you tried hitting `localhost:8080` in your browser?  What kind of web server are you using (Apache, Nginx)?

Comment: Yes, localhost:8080 works well, but i want it to be automatic. And yes, I have a tomcat server.